# Kotlin reading json unknown type Spring

Tags: json, spring, kotlin

I'm calling different APIs, that use the same key name in the JSON file. Depending on the response, there's one field that may be different types.

To be clear:

- The key "results" when calling the API nº1 is a JSON object
- The key "results" when calling the API nº2 is a JSON array

My code looks like this when using the second API:

```kotlin
data class Result(
    @SerializedName("results") var persons:ArrayList<Person> =ArrayList()
)
```

The question is if there's any way to use the same class, without taking care if it's a JSON array or a JSON object.

Comment: I would say your best bet is to create a custom deserializer.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can define results as an instance of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.`**`JsonNode`**.

```
data class Result(
    val results: JsonNode
)
```

Then you can process `results` based on it's type—whether it is an `ArrayNode` or an `ObjectNode` (as both extend `JsonNode`):

```
fun processResults(results: JsonNode) = when{
  results.isArray -> processArrayNode(results)
  else -> processObjectNode(results)
}

private fun processArrayNode(list: JsonNode): *return whatever you need*{
  val elements = list
             .elements()
             .asSequence()
             .toList()

  val mappedElements = elements.map{
    processObjectNode(it)
  }

// do whatever you need with the array
}

private fun processObjectNode(person: JsonNode): *return whatever you need*{
  //** this will transform the json node into a linkedHashMap where the keys are the json keys and the values are the values (here interpreted as jsonNodes) **/
  val fieldsMap = person
                .fields()
                .asSequence()
                .associateBy( {it.key}, {it.value} )
  
  // process whatever you need
}
```

This is one way to use the same DTO for both API calls. In my opinion, it is not worth the extra work. I would create two DTOs containing the `results` field, where in one it is an instance of `Person`, and in the other it is an instance of `List<Person>`.

**Edit:** One little upgrade to the above snippet would be to add extension methods to `JsonNode`:

```
fun JsonNode.elementsToList(): List<JsonNode> = this
    .elements()
    .asSequence()
    .toList()

fun JsonNode.fieldsToMap(): Map<String, JsonNode> = this
    .fields()
    .asSequence()
    .associateBy({it.key}, {it.value})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectMapper.typeFactory.constructParametricType` to handle generic types:

```kotlin
data class Result<T>(
  var x:T
)

val om = ObjectMapper()
om.registerModule(KotlinModule())
val parsedList = om.readValue<Result<List<String>>>(
  """{"x":["x1", "x2"]}""", 
  om.typeFactory.constructParametricType(Result::class.java, List::class.java)
)
println(parsedList)
val parsedMap = om.readValue<Result<Map<String, String>>>(
  """{"x":{"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}}""", 
  om.typeFactory.constructParametricType(Result::class.java, Map::class.java)
)
println(parsedMap)
```

Gives output:

```
Result(x=[x1, x2])
Result(x={k1=v1, k2=v2})
```